# Recreating display output from X11 Stream

Tags: x11

I do have two computers which are used to control an industrial plant. One of them controls the plant, the other is used as a failsafe. They are directly connected over ethernet, and the inactive" one just mirrors the display of the main controller.

I did capture the network traffic between the two and when i open it up in wireshark i see its all X11 traffic. It does include the initial connection request and also includes all the "draw calls" in plain text.

I now want to "replay" this captured stream and recreate the screen content from it. Is there any program available which can do so? Ideally directly from the wireshark capture file

My thoughts so far:
I can easily replay the network data itself and send it to some socket, but the communication is specific to the session, e.g. some commands refer to specific handle values set up earlier. Its unlikely a new session would work with the same values so i cant just pipe it into some program

Comment: Typically, if you want to mirror the appearance of an X11 screen, you would use vnc to recopy it to a 2nd remote display (also allowing kbd/mouse or not). Replaying the X11 protocol is going to be difficult. You might look at `xscope` which interprets the protocol stream and could be a basis for doing some sort of duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see from your connection is only your connection requests + events relevant to the windows created by you ( or other's client windows where your connection sets an event mask ), and because of that quite a lot is lost. I'm not aware of the programs that can reconstruct best possible version of the screen from one client traffic but it's certainly not possible to have 100% accurate copy of the screen and best possible model will be far away from real screen (unless your connection periodically polls for backing store content of each mapped window).

Comment: Is there existing software which can parse the commands and output an image/video? Getting output for only my own window is okay, since there is quite a lot of data in the traffic. Or some parsing libraries, anything so i dont have to parse the entire protocol on my own?

Comment: I'm not aware of any, what you want is some sort of "shadow xserver". Even if you care about your window only there is a lot of other things that can mess with it without your connection being aware ( unless you specifically try to notice everything - set as many event masks as possible, poll for window pixmap content etc )